# Face recognition using neural networks

Tags: c++, opencv

I am doing a project on face recognition, for that I have already used different methods like eigenface, fisherface, LBP histograms and surf. But these methods are not giving me an accurate result. Surf gives good matches for exact same images, but I need to match one image with it's own different poses(wearing glasses,side pose,if somebody is covering his face) etc. LBP compares histogram of images, i.e., only color informations. So when there is high variation on lighting condition it is not showing good results. So I heard about neural networks, but I don't know much about that. Is it possible to train the system very accurately by using neural networks. If possible how can we do that?

Comment: If you don't know much about neural networks, it will be quite a lot of work and research for you to implement something decent from scratch, I think.

Comment: opencv only offers a very primitive MLP ann. (that was state of the art 15 years ago) chances are low, that you can beat the existing face-reco methods using that.

Comment: "LBP compares histogram of images, i.e., only color informations" - you're wrong here. lbph compares histograms of greyscale neighbour intensity differences

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html#introductiontosvms) OpenCV page, there does seem to be some support for machine learning. That being said, the support does seem to be a bit limited.

What you could do, would be to:

1. User OpenCV to extract the face of the person.
2. Change the image to grey scale.
3. Try to manipulate so that the face is always the same size.

All the above *should* be doable with OpenCV itself (could be wrong, haven't messed with OpenCV in a while) so that should save you some time.

Next, you take the image, as a bitmap maybe, and feed the bitmap as a vector to the neural network. Alternatively, as @MatthiasB recommended, you could feed the features instead of individual pixels. This would simplify the data being passed, thus making the network easier to train.

As for training, you manipulate these images as above, and then feed them to the network. If a person uses glasses occasionally, you could have cases of the same person with and without glasses, etc.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to feed the ANN with features instead of individual pixels? The simpler the input, the easier it is to train.

Comment: @MatthiasB: I was not aware of that, I'll update the answer with your recommendation.

Comment: How can we feed bitmap as a vector to the neural network. Please explain the steps in detail..